# foreach and INSERT INTO not working

Tags: php, sql, twitter, foreach

right now I am facing the problem to get a small simple Twitter app to work properly. The problem is I want to store all tweets in a sql database for further research purpose (Master Thesis).Im trying to use 'INSERT INTO' to store the tweets in the db, but so far it doesn't work for me.

I would be happy for every hint or solution. 
Thanks a lot in advance.

So far so good, this is my code:

```
$getfield = "?screen_name=$user&count=$count";
$twitter = new TwitterAPIExchange($settings);
$string = json_decode ($twitter->setGetfield($getfield)
->buildOauth($url, $requestMethod)
->performRequest(),$assoc = True);
if ($string["errors"][0]["message"] != "")  
{echo "<h3> Sorry, there was a problem.</h3><p>Twitter returned the following error message:</p><p><em>".$string[errors][0]["message"]."</em></p>";exit();}
foreach($string as $items)
    {
        $created_at = $items['created_at'];
        $name = $items['user']['name'];

        mysqli_query($db,"INSERT INTO tweet_db (created_at, name) VALUES ('$created_at' '$name')") or die(mysql_error();

        mysqli_close($db);



    }
```

Answer (score 2):

you are missing a comma in insert statement:

```
mysqli_query($db,"INSERT INTO tweet_db (created_at, name) VALUES ('$created_at', '$name')") or die(mysql_error();
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the quick answer and the easy solution ;) I feel a little ashamed bothering you for only missing a comma. Everything works fine now. Thanks again!